# How do I render the following kind of table using Laravel Blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, include, laravel-blade

For a site being built in Laravel, I have tables with a lot of variability in the tds.
As such, I was thinking that it might make sense to pull the td rendering logic out into a separate view partial.

However, the following doesn't feel right, especially if the tables has hundreds of rows and lots of columns:

```
@foreach ($tableRows as $tableRow)
  @foreach ($tableCols as $tableCol)
    @include('partials.td', ['tableRow' => 'tableRow', 'tableCol' => 'tableCol'])
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

What's the best way to handle a view partial that may have to be included literally hundreds of times for a page to render?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way would be using Vue templates. create a Vue file in js/assets and put the template in there, passing variables of td as props
Vue will take care of the high number of data rows and will re-use things if possible.

BUT

if you want to reduce the load on the client side, your current way is OK; it can be improved a little, but for hundreds of rows of data, that's enough.

I still suggest putting the burden on the client-side.

Comment: I can certainly understand your recommendation, but I'd prefer to keep it server-side for now. That being said, is my naive recommendation okay? Would it make more sense to maybe make a component for the td and use that? Does Laravel optimize this behind the scenes by compiling the template once and then just continually calling the same function over and over again? I guess my main concern is how do I do this in a logical way that also isn't a huge burden on the server (client-side Vue rendering excluded). Thanks.

Comment: read this link, maybe it helps: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/06/vue-js-laravel-server-side-rendering/

Comment: Not sure if that really helps, but thank you for providing it. I need to read it again and think about it more.